# Compilation Memory Exhausted Error on running SQL on DDM table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I was experimenting with Dynamic Data Masking on a table. I have encountered a case wherein on running SQL on a table with DDM applied its failing with error
`SQL compilation error: Compilation memory exhausted.`

CASE 1: Created DDM using MD5 appending a default string(salt value),

```
create or replace masking policy hash_masking_str1 AS ( val string) RETURNS string ->
CASE
    WHEN is_role_in_session('ACCOUNTADMIN') THEN val
    ELSE md5(val||'|'||'TEXT')
END
alter table CUSTOMER_TBL modify column C_MKTSEGMENT set masking policy hash_masking_str1
```

Able to run SQL on table CUSTOMER_TBL using both ACCOUNTADMIN and other roles having select access on the table. DDM working fine.

Case 2: Created DDM using MD5 again. Now pulling default string(salt value) using another table.(Table has one row/one column)

```
create or replace masking policy hash_masking_str1 AS ( val string) RETURNS string ->
CASE
    WHEN is_role_in_session('ACCOUNTADMIN') THEN val
    ELSE md5(val||'|'||(select val from mask_values))
END
```

On running the SQL with ACCOUNTADMIN role I am able to get result from the table.
On using any other role the SQL is instantly failing with the compilation memory exhausted error.

Question: Is there anything wrong calling a select statement in DDM? Or is there any other way to pull the "salt" value from another table and use in MD5?

Comment: Sounds like Snowflake is not optimizing the Case 2 query very well. You might be best raising it with snowflake support.  Otherwise, maybe try putting the salt in an IMMUTABLE UDF, see if that make any difference.

Comment: Yes will submit a case to Snowflake. Though using a UDF like you mentioned is working.